# Check Two Condition If Object is Empty in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two variables "approved" and "verified". I only need to show the "Approve Button" if it is "verified" but not "approved"

**CODE**

```
  const checkIfShowApproveButton = (user) => {
    if (
      user &&
      user.verified &&
      user.approved &&
      Object.keys(user.verified).length &&
      Object.keys(user.approved) === null
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

**RESPONSE**

```
   {
  "id": 13,
  "approved": null,
  "verified": {
    "verified_at": "2020"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way  `Object.keys(user.approved).length === 0` it can't be `null`

```
const checkIfShowApproveButton = (user) => {
    if (
      user &&
      user.verified &&
      !user.approved &&
      Object.keys(user.verified).length
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Approve button doesn't show if it verified and not approved

Comment: yaa because you are having the a key in the `user.approved`

Comment: you can try second answer if `user.approved ` is not so imp

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't work. You must only show the "Approve Button" if it is "verified" but not "approved"

Comment: can you add the response code how its look when it's not  approved not

Comment: It has error. "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: sry me typo mistake, now it will work, edited again

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this code

```
const checkIfShowApproveButton = (user) => {
   return !!user && !!Object.entries(user).length && !!Object.entries(user.verified).length && !Object.entries(user.approved).length
}
```